# What is the reason that snapd is installed via apt and snap in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, snap

I see that `snapd` on Ubuntu 22.04 is installed via `apt`, but `snap info` also suggests that `snapd` is also installed as a snap package. Is there a good reason to keep it that way?

Comment: When you install snap by apt, you have snap/snapd. It's not something different

Comment: How do you even install snapd using snap?

Comment: ..and whats your problem with donkeys? ;-) Just kidding. As @muru implied, if you have no snapd, you can not use snap to install snapd.

Comment: The apt-installed snapd is slightly older. I was a bit surprised to discover that the apt package hasn't subsequently installed snapd via snap though. That'd make shipping snapd updates easier just like any other snap package. That's why I was wondering if there's any downside to installing snapd via snap.

Comment: Hey folks, this is a legit question. It is not opinion-based, but a common source of confusion about how snapd works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually need both.

You must have the `snapd` Debian package in order to install anything as a snap. You're right though: `snapd` is *also* distributed as a snap. However, it's never a snap you'll need to install yourself-- it'll get installed automatically. It's done this way so that `snapd` can update itself automatically using the typical snap mechanism instead of relying on you to update the Debian package. It also means you can try out different `snapd` channels to preview new features, and so on. Ultimately the `snapd` Debian package is a bootstrap that sets up the host to run snaps, and then re-executes the `snapd` shipped within the `snapd` snap.

The `snapd` Debian package used to use the `core` snap for this same purpose. If you don't see the `snapd` snap installed, it means your `apt`-installed `snapd` is re-executing into the `core` snap instead.

Importantly, note that everything I say here only applies to Ubuntu. Snapd on other distros may behave differently. For example, last I checked, Fedora completely disables this re-exec functionality. I'm not sure if the snapd snap is still pulled in, but if so it's not actually used.

Comment: I don't see the snapd snap installed on any of my systems. The snapd from the stable channel is a bit newer than the one I have, which is installed via apt. So it seems that the snapd snap isn't installed by default but I could install it if I wanted to.

Comment: That probably means you have an older snapd. In that case, it's using the `core` snap for the same purpose. The `snapd` snap type is a somewhat-recent invention.

Comment: @kyrofa re "is a somewhat-recent invention", thank you, because that explains the emergence of the question in the first place, at least why it emerged in me. Or in more bare terms, me failing to remember that there used to be both vs. recently seeing both. So the actual question for me was "I'm seeing both snapd's - is it supposed to be this way or should I try to get rid of one of them for the sake of system cleanliness?" Both this (i.e. it should be this way, you cannot and should not get rid of either if you want to use snaps) and the "why" being neatly addressed by this answer.